# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError - on MAC OSX - Unsupported class file major version 56

Tags: java, apache-spark

I try to run Python code that refers to Apache Spark on Mac OSX 10.14.4 but I seem to have a problem with Java Class versions and I am not able to sort out the problem. It has to probably to do with the Java versions but I do not recognize the problem and how to solve it.

```
I installed version of Spark: spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7, 
I installed the latest version of Java JDK
```

### Java versions in the terminal window give the following result:

```
java -version

>java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
>Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
>Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version

>javac 12.0.1
```

### Warnings during startup of Jupiter Notebook for Python

startup in the Terminal window

```
$ pyspark

[I 20:47:14.841 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from /Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 20:47:14.841 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/myname/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 20:47:14.852 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/myname
[I 20:47:14.852 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 20:47:14.852 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 20:47:14.852 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=0666955663ecb246ee569680e4e8e7afbdd3d64b0efcfc75
[I 20:47:14.852 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 20:47:14.896 NotebookApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=0666955663ecb246ee569680e4e8e7afbdd3d64b0efcfc75&token=0666955663ecb246ee569680e4e8e7afbdd3d64b0efcfc75
[I 20:47:15.555 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from 127.0.0.1
[I 20:47:24.920 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[I 20:47:27.600 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 2ff964f7-da2a-4427-9aaa-ff9f96967512

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/Applications/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.1.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

19/04/22 20:47:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[W 20:47:37.658 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 2ff964f7-da2a-4427-9aaa-ff9f96967512
19/04/22 20:47:39 WARN MacAddressUtil: Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: a1:17:d6:b3:ce:11:0b:4c
[I 20:47:41.088 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 2ff964f7-da2a-4427-9aaa-ff9f96967512
[I 20:49:27.467 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled1.ipynb
```

I able to run Python code in the Notebook as long as it is not referring to Spark. The warnings also occurred when Spark was starting up in the Terminal window before the Jupyter Notebook was configured.

### This is the python code I used in the Notebook:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
import numpy as np
TOTAL = 10000
dots = sc.parallelize([2.0 * np.random.random(2) - 1.0 for i in range(TOTAL)]).cache()
print("Number of random points:", dots.count())
```

### Error report

When I run the code I get the following error message below. The goals is to be able to run the program without this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/Applications/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py 
in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327   "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328   format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329   else:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 56
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)

More error lines not copied here
```

### My question

I am not so familiar with the Java and Apache Spark environment. Can you provide instructions on how to solve this error? Do you know if th eWarnings during the startup of the Jupiter Notebook can be solved? If you require require further information, please let me know.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Switch to java 1.8

Comment: Hello Sai,Thank you for your quick response. I am not so failiar with the technical things of Java. Could you further explain what I have to do to use Java 1.8? Instructions in layman's term would be helpful. I added the screen log when pyspark starts up there are warnings, do these have an influence? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Download and install Java 8: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
and set path variable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Spark 2.4 was complied with 1.8 and if you install and set the path variable, you can alleviate this problem. Alternatively, if you cannot move away from Java 12, you can try compiling spark from the source with Java 12

Comment: Hello Sai, Thank you for the instructions and the clarification. I was able to solve this problem.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

TLDR

Switch to Java 1.8 by installing one of [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and setting env var by [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)